# how to validate a input field using veevalidate with CDN

Tags: vee-validate

here i am using VeeValidate Form Validation Library For Vue Js. Using CDN i am trying to achieve this but i am not able to validate the email input fields. SO where i am going wrong please tell if any one can find the issue.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- jsdelivr cdn -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<!-- cloudflair cdn -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vee-validate/2.1.1/vee-validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input v-validate="'required|email'" name="email" type="text">
    <span>{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vee-validate/2.2.9/vee-validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vee-validate/rules@4.4.7/dist/vee-validate-rules.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div>
    <input v-validate="'required|email'" name="email" type="text">
    <span>{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

You forgot to bind a Vue object to an HTML element i.e

```
new Vue({
 el: '#root',
});
```

I also added the vee validate plugin using

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
```

**Please note am using Vue 2 not 3**